# Combining greyscale images through averaging

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, colors

I have a program which uses `getRed()`, `getGreen()` and `getBlue()` which works fine. Im looking to see if I can find some other algorithms which also color greyscale images, whether it be more or less accurate it doesnt matter, its just something im looking into to compare the methods and their accuracy.
I decided to use a similar method, just by using `getRed()` for image 1, 2 and 3 (as opposed to just 1) and dividing by 3 for each colour, in theory achieving the average red, green and blue values across the 3 images and creating a new image from it.

The resulting image is quite strange; the colors arent uniform i.e. random colours for each pixel, you can barely make out any characteristics of the image as its so grainy, I suppose is the best way to describe it. It looks like a normal photograph but with colour noise everywhere. Just wondering if anyone knew why this is happening? It wasnt my intentions and was expecting much more normal, quite similar to the original method but maybe more subdued/brighter colors for each.

Anyone know why this is happening? It doesnt seem right. Are there any other methods I could use to colour the images apart from the standard `getRGB()` ways?

```
BufferedImage combinedImage = new BufferedImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), image1.getType());
        for(int x = 0; x < combinedImage.getWidth(); x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < combinedImage.getHeight(); y++)
                combinedImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(
                new Color((image1.getRGB(x, y) + image2.getRGB(x, y) + image3.getRGB(x, y))/3).getRed(), 
                new Color((image1.getRGB(x, y) + image2.getRGB(x, y) + image3.getRGB(x, y))/3).getGreen(), 
                new Color((image1.getRGB(x, y) + image2.getRGB(x, y) + image3.getRGB(x, y))/3).getBlue()).
                getRGB());
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

getRGB() returns the int representations of a pixel, including the alpha channel. Since a int is 4-byte (32 bits), this int will be like this:

```
01010101 11111111 10101010 11111111
  Alpha     Red     Green    Blue
```

When you add the three values, this is using the alpha channel too, so I guess this is making you get strange results. Also, adding ints this way can cause "overflow" in one of the channels. For example, if one pixel has a blue value of 255 and another one has a value of 2, the sum will have a value 1 for green and value 1 for blue.

To extract each color channel from the int you can do this.

```
red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
green = (rgb >>8 ) & 0xFF;
blue = (rgb) & 0xFF;
```

(This is what Color class does internally inside getRed(), getBlue() and getGreen() http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java#Color.getRed%28%29)

Then, combine the colors like this:

```
combinedImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(
((image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 16 & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 16 & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 16 & 0xFF))/3, 
((image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 8 & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 8 & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) >> 8 & 0xFF))/3, 
((image1.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF) + (image1.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF))/3).
getRGB());
```

Or use `new Color(image1.getRGB(x, y)).getRed()` each time for each image.

```
combinedImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(
    (new Color(image1.getRGB(x, y)).getRed() + new Color(image2.getRGB(x, y)).getRed() + new Color(image3.getRGB(x, y)).getRed())/3, 
    (new Color(image1.getRGB(x, y)).getGreen() + new Color(image2.getRGB(x, y)).getGreen() + new Color(image3.getRGB(x, y)).getGreen())/3, 
    (new Color(image1.getRGB(x, y)).getBlue() + new Color(image2.getRGB(x, y)).getBlue() + new Color(image3.getRGB(x, y)).getBlue())/3).
    getRGB());
```

Comment: Ah that would make sense, thank you. When I use the code you posted im getting an error saying int cannot be dereferenced and can only make it work by doing it the way I was before, any ideas on this? I appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, as I say I appreciate it. The images are definitely combined, however, the output image is just grey. The only reason I can think of is that its not going over 255 and so when dividing by 3 the R, G, B values are often the same, resulting in the greys?

Comment: @user2517280 It may depend on the input images. I tested it with these images: http://imgur.com/a/tQjQX and worked fine.

Comment: when using three greyscale images as the input, I only receive an averaged greyscale image as the ouput, whilst it looks good in terms of combining them, im looking to colour them and was hoping to get the average value and then assigning it to the red, green and blue values but this doesnt seem to be working, I thought it would in theory?